# Is it possible to merge incomplete events into a KTable?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I wonder if the KTable would meet our needs.

Let's say I have a topic `myTopic` in Kafka that contains events, and I plug a KafkaStreams App on this topic.

Let's assume at time `t0`, the `myTopic` contains 3 events:

```
"key_1": { "col_1": "val_k1_c1_@t0", "col_2": "val_k1_c2_@t0"}
"key_2": { "col_1": "val_k2_c1_@t0", "col_2": "val_k2_c2_@t0"}
"key_3": { "col_1": "val_k3_c1_@t0", "col_3": "val_k3_c3_@t0"}
```

At time `t1`, a new event related to `key_1` is pushed into `myTopic`:

```
"key_1": {"col_1": "NEWVAL_k1_c1_@t1", "col_2": "NEWVAL_k1_c2_@t1"}
```

So at time `t1`, the KTable can be represented this way:

```
KEY         COL_1               COL_2               COL_3

key_1       NEWVAL_k1_c1_@t1    NEWVAL_k1_c2_@t1
key_2       val_k2_c1_@t0       val_k2_c2_@t0
key_3       val_k3_c1_@t0                           val_k3_c3_@t0
```

That is the key concept of the KTable: to keep the latest value for a given key.

Now let's assume that at time `t2`, a new event arrives, in order to enrich to `key_1`:

```
"key_1": { "col_3": "val_k1_c3_@t2" }
```

If my understanding is OK, the KTable will lose the values for `col_1` and `col_2`, and the table will look this way:

```
KEY         COL_1               COL_2               COL_3

key_1                                               val_k1_c3_@t2
key_2       val_k2_c1_@t0       val_k2_c2_@t0
key_3       val_k3_c1_@t0                           val_k3_c3_@t0
```

Did I understand the concept?

Is there a native way to merge the values in order the KTable to look like this ?

```
KEY         COL_1               COL_2               COL_3

key_1       NEWVAL_k1_c1_@t1    NEWVAL_k1_c2_@t1    val_k1_c3_@t2
key_2       val_k2_c1_@t0       val_k2_c2_@t0
key_3       val_k3_c1_@t0                           val_k3_c3_@t0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understanding is correct. Note, that a `KTable` treats each record as a "complete" record that updates the whole row. Thus, conceptually, `"key_1": { "col_3": "val_k1_c3_@t2" }` in interpreted as `col_1: null` and `col_2: null`.

However, instead of reading the topic directly as a KTable, you can read it as a `KStream` and do an `aggregation()`. This allows you to update the result `KTable` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Matthias. I managed to merge my JSON events by creating a KGroupedStream grouped by key, and then to merge the JSON attributes by aggregating into a KTable. The next step will be to export/check the content of the KTable, because if I toStream().to(myTopic), the topic contents the events, not only the "last" one for each key. (That makes sense as I transform the KTable into a KStream.) But this is another story, and I have some time to give to this task. I will open a new question if I am totally lost :) Thank you again Matthias !